# Плохо функционирует скрипт из-за того, что он срабатывает раньше чем подгружаются стили

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть скрипт, который обрабатывает svg. Его целью является изменение слова и растяжка его на всю высоту экрана. Но возникла такая проблема, что если перезагрузить страницу через ctrl+F5, он сначала растягивает слово со стандартным шрифтом (скриншот 1), а потом подгружаются стили и слово сжимается (скриншот 2):

[image: Скриншот 1]
[image: Скриншот 2]

HTML:

```
<!--...-->
<svg viewBox="-2.5 0.5 16 75">
      <g transform="rotate(90 0 0)">
          <text id="text0"></text>
      </g>
</svg>
<!--...-->
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //.....................
    let text = document.getElementById("text0");
    text.innerHTML= "<tspan fill='#282828'>OCTOPU</tspan><tspan fill='#191919'>S</tspan>";
    document.querySelector("#string0").querySelector("svg").setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `-2.5 0.2 16 ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`);
    //.....................
});
```

Comment: Если после этого перезагружать просто через F5, то все хорошо

Comment: У вас `потом подгружаются стили` или `потом подгружаются шрифты`?... Уточните, ибо это разные вещи.

Comment: Шрифты указаны в стилях, по этому так подумал. Хотя они из Гугл фонтс, так что вполне вероятно что именно шрифты подгружаются позже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шрифты подгружаются асинхронно. `$(document).ready` срабатывает когда готова DOM, и на данном этапе картинки и шрифты еще могут подгружаться. Выход один - делать прелоадер шрифта на AJAX, и запускать ваш фикс, когда шрифт гарантированно загружен. Более тупой вариант - сделать все в момент onload:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

  // все на странице уже подгрузилось

});
```

Еще имейте в виду `$(window).on('load', ...)` ни в коем случае не должен быть внутри обработчика `$(document).ready(...)`.

Comment: попробовал этим способом и способом с таймером (даже на большое время), все-равно после ctrl+F5 и так и так оно так же сначала создает текст с обычным шрифтом, потом считает высоту и потом только дает нормальный шрифт

Comment: все, я разобрался. до этого я брал все три строки и делал их внутри он лоад, сейчас я сначала выполнил первые две строки, и только потом выполняется третья в он лоад. теперь все работает, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //.....................
    setTimeout(() => {
      let text = document.getElementById("text0");
      text.innerHTML= "<tspan fill='#282828'>OCTOPU</tspan><tspan fill='#191919'>S</tspan>";
      document.querySelector("#string0").querySelector("svg").setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `-2.5 0.2 16       ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`);
    });
    //.....................
});
```

Можно попробовать таким костылём сделать. Но выглядит плохо