# Как убрать стандартный шрифт до подгрузки Google Fonts или получить событие их готовности?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, шрифты

Есть скрипт, который обрабатывает svg. Его целью является изменение слова и растяжка его на всю высоту экрана. Но возникла такая проблема, что если перезагрузить страницу через ctrl+F5, он сначала растягивает слово со стандартным шрифтом (скриншот 1), а потом подгружаются стили и слово сжимается (скриншот 2). Похожий вопрос я уже задавал, и решение, в принципе, есть ([https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1156837/Плохо-функционирует-скрипт-из-за-того-что-он-срабатывает-раньше-чем-подгружаютс/1156879#1156879](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1156837/%D0%9F%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81/1156879#1156879)), но из-за определенных особенностей программы мне нужно чтобы стандартный шрифт в принципе не устанавливался на странице до того как подгрузятся шрифты гугл фонтс или получить событие их готовности.

[image: Скриншот 1]
[image: Скриншот 2]

HTML:

```
<svg viewBox="-2.5 0.5 16 75">
      <g transform="rotate(90 0 0)">
          <text id="text0"></text>
      </g>
</svg>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //.....................
    let text = document.getElementById("text0");
    text.innerHTML= "<tspan fill='#282828'>OCTOPU</tspan><tspan fill='#191919'>S</tspan>";
    document.querySelector("#string0").querySelector("svg").setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `-2.5 0.2 16 ${text.getComputedTextLength()}`);
    //.....................
});
```

Comment: Попробуйте вынести подгруз шрифта в отдельный link такого рода: `<link rel='preload' as='font' href='<some font href>' />`. Тогда он подгрузится быстро (но все равно асинхронно). Ну а там цепляйтесь к onload и делайте магию с svg. Это, вероятно, все равно не 100-процентный вариант, но может помочь